# Google Apps email messages being flanged as "failed fraud detection" on outlook

Tags: outlook, mx-record, spf, gmail

mx entries for gmail and spf code for gmail is in place on cpanel however every time I try and send an email from my google apps account it gets picked up as fraud on outlook, and spf=softfail (if this means anything) + X-AUTH-Result: FAIL X-SID-Result: FAIL. not sure what to do, can anyone help me explain why its doing so or how to fix it?

Would be much appreciated :)

## Email message source

```
x-store-info:sbevkl2QZR7OXo7WID5ZcdV2tiiWGqTng3IUzOU9+MR74e+pFoKt57tG8IFvufpyUgk5e+E3tMfBNtQSdDXnpfPgCQ+dHO2XB5j3sOmosWXyjc7RwoXTbFuTpyWXoVIqhDMoFjarHWw=
Authentication-Results: hotmail.com; spf=softfail (sender IP is 209.85.212.177) smtp.mailfrom=vitor.zanatta@metafourmarketing.com; dkim=none header.d=metafourmarketing.com; x-hmca=fail header.id=vitor.zanatta@metafourmarketing.com
X-SID-PRA: vitor.zanatta@metafourmarketing.com
X-AUTH-Result: FAIL
X-SID-Result: FAIL
X-Message-Status: n:n
X-Message-Delivery: Vj0xLjE7dXM9MDtsPTA7YT0xO0Q9MTtHRD0xO1NDTD0w
X-Message-Info: gamVN+8Ez8V+RHg+F+brAcUtnc2tK8YOQqQVLIrAXQR9K2G5wgw4nT1VIYn/KHRnD+IYwuec84K6tcy7Is6Ss2MgJ4PlySgAUqWozo5l+fYqhPiGji5blgvi8kmjBA78Zp4kCzYi+g+7SSQWcN587JOdcyS/LuYczYUNm2rYukbNgPKRyvNlprEiPAR5jmb4Iki9p0J28q2e6qPg79+bjAdXrQi4LeF+JTmMNhKqcLAnqV9qHjFPWw==
Received: from mail-wi0-f177.google.com ([209.85.212.177]) by BAY004-MC6F35.hotmail.com over TLS secured channel with Microsoft SMTPSVC(7.5.7601.23143);
 Tue, 15 Sep 2015 10:49:10 -0700
Received: by mail-wi0-f177.google.com with SMTP id lk2so39741062wic.0
    for <vitorrzanatta@hotmail.co.uk>; Tue, 15 Sep 2015 10:49:10 -0700 (PDT)
X-Google-DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed;
    d=1e100.net; s=20130820;
    h=x-gm-message-state:mime-version:date:message-id:subject:from:to
     :content-type;
    bh=EQXn6mG+rbpwXFk2fVwPSpJMO8OlKhDnaXA0Ylgza+Q=;
    b=Sz8d47fqkur8v1T0xrfeN/6b1NL7myZjoufVtVUqyP/N72c1jpGAiOZSYNr/Nj0DOP
     SfbEX/iXVxm5TaPvmGS/lQ1aEx6QV+NaU06DcQbEgwmUT4oB4dfyqzbCMZaAs0P0GflK
     yDwvd4eDiNNZd6xlpeVRWsbhR993LnZ9kLcOlzVjcIzd8Xc14Mn7Io/MHnSw/sPq6iio
     ixLwcJkYQXAh5v8Ok5H0h68qbEr0AV5JdRHiz4DoVZOkUSgaR/iLZU/K/RUuHuP9taMv
     3fBDnr5eqjTZpHiNEvWXfaCd0XLwxJWFid5qIaf6usIxB3r5Mtw42tlId2LSemioKxPE
     dWrA==
X-Gm-Message-State: ALoCoQla+u02xakQLzkYeJIgnbfS3HyNEdWA0qKoUbQ+KMx5NfRkPpvUAx5p+e6t5Sdq1cNGjf4m
MIME-Version: 1.0
X-Received: by 10.180.10.101 with SMTP id h5mr9254303wib.22.1442339350540;
Tue, 15 Sep 2015 10:49:10 -0700 (PDT)
Received: by 10.28.178.80 with HTTP; Tue, 15 Sep 2015 10:49:10 -0700 (PDT)
Date: Tue, 15 Sep 2015 18:49:10 +0100
Message-ID: <CACm8JCqPEK0GLF8MhR5ZE6CG5Vh3=mB=D7ahGDxyGBN=ugxugg@mail.gmail.com>
Subject: test
From: Vitor Zanatta <vitor.zanatta@metafourmarketing.com>
To: vitorrzanatta@hotmail.co.uk
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary=001a11c26816a28e76051fcccc98
Return-Path: vitor.zanatta@metafourmarketing.com
X-OriginalArrivalTime: 15 Sep 2015 17:49:10.0826 (UTC) FILETIME=[D3C278A0:01D0EFDE]
```

Comment: if you're going to use my answer at least market it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

include google servers if you are sending from google servers:

```
v=spf1 mx ip4:184.171.248.66 include:_spf.google.com ~all
```

You can also test to ensure this is working with http://testexchangeconnectivity.com and Select 'Outbound SMTP Test'

+a and ip4:184.171.248.66 are redundant, always prefer IP addresses to save DNS Lookup limit of 10.